# Where + and where from Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Now I have the following query:

```
$passed = Deployment::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(15)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

But now I would like to add a second where like this: `WHERE closed_domain == 0`.

But how can I add this to the current query? I've tried ::andWhere but with no success... .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep building the query before you call the `get()`.

```
$passed = Deployment::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(15))
    ->where('closed_domain', 0)
    ->where(.....)
    ->get();
```

Comment: If you need an explanation, let me know.